# excel macro VBA search and print file

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me please creating a macro with search file from disk, 
look in: `C:\Etikety\Stitky\`. 
I search a name which contain in cell `C2` 
and file type is `.lbe`
When file found print it.
I would implemate this part of code into this code. Thank for reply

---

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub zadat()

Dim reg, check As String
Dim i, j, done As Integer
reg = Cells(2, 3).Value
check = Cells(4, 3).Value

If check = "True" Then

    i = 2
    j = 1
    done = 0
    Do While Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) <> ""
        If Sheets("data").Cells(i, j) = reg Then
            done = Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3)
            done = done + 1
            Sheets("data").Cells(i, j + 3) = done
            Exit Do
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Loop
Else
    MsgBox ("Chyba, oprav!!!")
End If

Cells(3, 3) = ""

Cells(3, 3).Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Cells(1, 1).row

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit and try following code as per your need:

```
Sub find_N_print()
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = "C:\Etikety\Stitky\" & Range("C2").Value & ".lbe"
    file = Dir(filePath)
    If file <> "" Then
        Application.PrintOut Filename:=filePath & file
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, please can you implemate this part of code with my code? Thank you very much