Setting Normal.dotm template on Word Docs for Directory and SubDirectories VBA
I am trying to remove links to templates on a large number of word documents spread a large directory and subdirectories. So far, I have been able to remove templates on individual documents, or an a directory, but not on subdirectories. I have been trying to utilize Graham Mayor's Batch processes utility https://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm
but to no avail. No errors are reported and all files in a test directory are listed as having been modified but none of them have the normal template instead of the prior specified templates. I am also open to using Powershell for this, but i have not investigated how to do that yet and have a sunken cost in VBA at this point.
Here is my Function used in Graham Mayor's tool:
Function TemplateReplace(oDoc As Document) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    With ActiveDocument
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
        .AttachedTemplate = _
            ""
    End With
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Function
Err_Handler:
  TemplateReplace = False
  Resume lbl_Exit
End Function

This code returns no errors and claims it completes successfully, but the template still shows as the prior specified template instead of the normal.dotm necessary.
I also have the entirety of my code that I have successfully used to change the template for all documents in a directory, but not subdirectories, in case that is easier to modify. Source for this info:
https://www.litigationsupporttipofthenight.com/single-post/2020/07/21/vba-code-to-run-a-macro-on-multiple-word-files
Sub RunMacroMultipleFiles()

Dim File

Dim path As String

' this code taken from Running a macro on all files in a folder - Tips for Module Creation

' Path to your folder. MY folder is listed below. I bet yours is different.

' make SURE you include the terminating "\"

'YOU MUST EDIT THIS.

path = "MYPATH"

'Change this file extension to the file you are opening. .htm is listed below. You may have rtf or docx.

'YOU MUST EDIT THIS.

File = Dir(path & "*.docx")

Do While File <> ""

Documents.Open FileName:=path & File

' This is the call to the macro you want to run on each file the folder

'YOU MUST EDIT THIS. You put your Macro name here.

Call TemplateRemoval

' set file to next in Dir

File = Dir()

Loop

End Sub

Sub TemplateRemoval()
'
' TemplateRemoval Macro
'
'
    With ActiveDocument
        
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
        .AttachedTemplate = _
            ""
        .Close _
            SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, _
            OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
    End With
End Sub


This second code block would work if it could filter through subdirectories, but I have over 300 directories to go through and that isn't feasible.

Example of including subfolders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286419/478884

Thank you @Tim. Could the call for this be as simple as
Sub RemoveAll()
For Each in GetFileMatches
Call TemplateRemoval
Next
End Sub

Nothing about this question is related to powershell. Tag removed.

You may want to look at https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/process_batch_folder_addin.html and http://www.gmayor.com/document_batch_processes.htm which are utilities for processing batches of documents (including subfolders).

@charles Hi, I have seen your name on several forums concerning this topic so thats cool to see you respond to my question. I actually tried to use The batch process tools but was unable to get them to actually modify my documents. This is documented in the post above, and the first block of code is the function i was attempting to use in graham mayor's version of the tool. Thanks

Something like this should work:
Sub RunMacroMultipleFiles()

    Const ROOT_PATH As String = "C:\Temp\" 'for example
    
    Dim docFiles As Collection, f As Object, doc As Document
    
    Set docFiles = GetFileMatches(ROOT_PATH, "*.docx") 
    
    For Each f In docFiles
        Set doc = Documents.Open(f.path)
        TemplateRemoval doc 'pass document to `TemplateRemoval`
    Next f
End Sub

Sub TemplateRemoval(doc As Document)
    With doc
        .UpdateStylesOnOpen = False
        .AttachedTemplate = ""
        .Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, _
            OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat
    End With
End Sub

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFileMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection  'for files to be returned
    Dim colSub As New Collection    'for queueing subfolders

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder  'start point for searching

    Do While colSub.Count > 0 'while have any folders to check...

        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1)) 'get the next folder
        colSub.Remove 1                     '...and remove from the queue 

        For Each f In fldr.Files 'check files in this folder
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f

        If subFolders Then 'any subfolders to add to the queue?
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.path
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFileMatches = colFiles
End Function


Tim you are a livesaver, I have never used VBA before last week and have been working on this on and off with no success. I have one final question. When trying to run this, under RunMacroMultipleFiles, docfiles = GetFileMatches(ROOT_PATH, "*.docx", True) breaks and says argument not optional.
Well, i can see that you listed the boolean value as optional, and i have applied it anyways but that still did not resolve it. I cant figure out what argument it is still expecting? I apologize if you feel you are force feeding me.

Sorry typo - should be Set docfiles = GetFileMatches(ROOT_PATH, "*.docx", True)  See if that fixes it.  You shouldn't need to include the last argument unless you don't want it to scan subfolders.

I actually figured this out on my own and was tabbing back to let you know. thank you for your assistance once again. it works perfectly!
