# Extracting Attachments from *.msg files stored in many subfolders

Tags: vba, outlook, subdirectory, email-attachments, msg

The below code extracts attachments from *.msg files stored in one folder.

I'm seeking to extract attachments from *.msg files stored in many subfolders within a folder.

The path for the main Folder is:
U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder

The paths for the subfolders are:
U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder\Folder1
U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder\Folder2
U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder\Folder3
etc.

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()

Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim strAttPath As String

    'path for msgs
strFilePath = "U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder\"
    'path for saving attachments
strAttPath = "D\Attachments\"

strFile = Dir(strFilePath & "*.msg")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strFilePath & strFile)
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
         For Each att In msg.Attachments
             att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.FileName
         Next
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders/20688126#20688126

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your prompt response. Much appreciated. As my VBA knowledge is limited, can you do me a favor & combine the two code together. Thank you again Tim :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA macro that search for file in multiple subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders)

Comment: Thank you FoxCy. I would be grateful if the codes can be combined together to extract all the attachments from the resulted *.msg files. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my answer from [VBA macro that search for file in multiple subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders/20688126#20688126)

```
Sub SaveOlAttachments()

    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim att As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strAttPath As String
    Dim colFiles As New Collection, f

    'path for msgs
    strFilePath = "U:\XXXXX\XXXXX\Main Folder\"

    GetFiles strFilePath , "*.msg", True, colFiles

    'path for saving attachments
    strAttPath = "D\Attachments\"

    For Each f in colFiles
        Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(f)
        If msg.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
             For Each att In msg.Attachments
                 att.SaveAsFile strAttPath & att.FileName
             Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Sub to perform the search:

```
Sub GetFiles(StartFolder As String, Pattern As String, _
             DoSubfolders As Boolean, ByRef colFiles As Collection)

    Dim f As String, sf As String, subF As New Collection, s

    If Right(StartFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartFolder = StartFolder & "\"

    f = Dir(StartFolder & Pattern)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        colFiles.Add StartFolder & f
        f = Dir()
    Loop

    sf = Dir(StartFolder, vbDirectory)
    Do While Len(sf) > 0
        If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(StartFolder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                    subF.Add StartFolder & sf
            End If
        End If
        sf = Dir()
    Loop

    For Each s In subF
        GetFiles CStr(s), Pattern, True, colFiles
    Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for your efforts. I tried the code but I'm getting Compile error, Sub or Function not defined. Any thoughts from your side?

Comment: Did you copy the `GetFiles` sub from the linked question?  I've added it above.

Comment: It worked amazingly! Thank you so much Tim. Wish you all the best in your life & career. Have a great day ahead!