# FOR EACH Loop with Words

Tags: excel, vba

How can I use words to apply FOR EACH loops? Suppose I have 96 separate csv files as follows and need to change the very first cell of each. The files are

```
c:\2010\2010_jan_apple.csv
c:\2010\2010_jan_orange.csv
c:\2010\2010_feb_apple.csv
c:\2010\2010_feb_orange.csv
...  
c:\2010\2010_dec_apple.csv
c:\2010\2010_dec_orange.csv
c:\2012\2011_jan_apple.csv
c:\2012\2011_jan_orange.csv
...  
c:\2016\2016_dec_apple.csv
c:\2016\2016_dec_orange.csv
```

So I think there would be one FOR loop and two FOR EACH loops.

```
year=2010,2012,2014,2016  
month=jan,feb,...,dec  
type=apple,orange
```

My silly code is

```
sub a()
application.displayalerts=false
for year=2010 to 2016 step 2
workbooks.open "c:\" & year & "\" & year & "_jan_apple.csv"
cells(1,1)="apple"
with activeworkbook
.saveas
.close
end with
workbooks.open "c:\" & year & "\" & year & "_jan_orange.csv"
cells(1,1)="orange"
with activeworkbook
.saveas
.close
end with
...
next year
end sub
```

In VBA, can I create a list such as {"jan","feb",...,"dec"} or {"apple","orange"} to employ FOR EACH iteration? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only "Apple and Oranges" then you do not need a loop for that. If you have more "fruits" then yes, you will require a loop. Also you do not need to have an array for the month names. You could get that from `MonthName()`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim flName As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim yr As Long

    For yr = 2010 To 2016 Step 2
        For i = 1 To 12
            flName = "c:\" & yr & "\" & yr & "_" & Left(MonthName(i), 3) & "_apple.csv"
            'UpdateWb flName, "apple"
            Debug.Print flName
            flName = "c:\" & yr & "\" & yr & "_" & Left(MonthName(i), 3) & "_orange.csv"
            'UpdateWb flName, "orange"
            Debug.Print flName
        Next i
    Next yr
End Sub

Sub UpdateWb(f As String, fruit As String)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(flName)
    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = fruit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close (True)
    DoEvents
LetsContinue:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

If you have more fruits then you can use a 3rd loop. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim flName As String
    Dim fruits() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim yr As Long
    Dim itm As Variant

    '~~> Add more if required
    fruits = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Guava")

    For yr = 2010 To 2016 Step 2
        For i = 1 To 12
            For Each itm In fruits
                'c:\2010\2010_jan_apple.csv
                flName = "c:\" & yr & "\" & yr & "_" & Left(MonthName(i), 3) & "_" & itm & ".csv"
                'UpdateWb flName, itm
                Debug.Print flName
            Next itm
        Next i
    Next yr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you're having real files, as your code shows, you can loop through them. 
Here's one example showing how to do that:

[Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("c:\testfolder\*test*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

In your case as the files are in different folders, you can recursively iterate..

[VBA macro that search for file in multiple subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders)

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Folder

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        Call TestSub(mySubFolder.Path)
        Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
    Next

End Function

Sub TestR()

    Call Recurse("D:\Projets\")

End Sub
```