# How to get the filename with csv extension

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to get file name with csv extension , but when i try to debug.print it always print the .csv file and the .txt file

im search the file in the folder and subfolder

heres the code

```
Sub LoopAllSubFolders(ByVal folderPath As String)

Dim fileName As String
Dim fullFilePath As String
Dim numFolders As Long
Dim folders() As String
Dim i As Long

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.*", vbDirectory)

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then

        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName

        If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory And Not (fullFilePath Like "*csv*")) = vbDirectory Then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        Else
            'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
            'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
            Debug.Print folderPath & fileName
        End If

    End If

    fileName = Dir()

Wend

For i = 0 To numFolders - 1

    LoopAllSubFolders folders(i)

Next i

End Sub
```

The code i get from website and i add `not like "*csv*"`

perhaps someone can correcting the code,

thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA macro that search for file in multiple subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687810/vba-macro-that-search-for-file-in-multiple-subfolders)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")` to find all csv files in `folderPath`.

```vb
If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv")

While Len(fileName) <> 0

    If Left(fileName, 1) <> "." Then
        fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName
        ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
        folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
        numFolders = numFolders + 1
    End If

    fileName = Dir()
Wend
```

## new edition: use `FileSystemObject`

Use `FileSystemObject` to get names of subfolders then get all csv files in each subfolder

```vb
Dim fso as object, mainFolder as object, subFolder as object, file

set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if fso.FolderExists("folderPath") Then
    set mainFolder = fso.getfolder("folderPath")
else
    exit sub
end if

for each subFolder in mainFolder.subfolders
    for each file in subFolder.Files
        if file.name like "*.csv" then
            ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
            folders(numFolders) = file
            numFolders = numFolders + 1
        end if
    next file
next subFolder
```

Comment: i think it makes sense, but the folderPath has only subfolders , and inside the subfolders will have .txt and .csv files , thats why if i use the folderPath & "*.csv*" files, it wont work

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
    fullFilePath = folderPath & fileName

   If (GetAttr(fullFilePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
        ReDim Preserve folders(0 To numFolders) As String
        folders(numFolders) = fullFilePath
        numFolders = numFolders + 1
   Else
     If Right(fileName, 4) = ".csv" Then 'new line
       'Insert the actions to be performed on each file
        'This example will print the full file path to the immediate window
        Debug.Print folderPath & fileName
    End If
```