# Changing cell color while adding items to a collection

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a macro that finds files that are randomly put in folder/subfolders and opens them if they are found by reading down a list in column B.  It works perfectly but it only skips over the cells if that file doesn't exist, I would like to change the color of the cell if it is not found.  The top half of the code is from someone else and I've tried altering it but can't find a way to have this happen. Instead of adding a file path that doesn't exist it only skips over it.

```
Sub GetFiles(StartFolder As String, Pattern As String, _
         DoSubfolders As Boolean, ByRef colFiles As Collection)

Dim f As String, sf As String, subF As New Collection, s

If Right(StartFolder, 1) <> "\" Then StartFolder = StartFolder & "\"

f = Dir(StartFolder & Pattern)
Do While Len(f) > 0
    colFiles.Add StartFolder & f
    f = Dir()
Loop

sf = Dir(StartFolder, vbDirectory)
Do While Len(sf) > 0
    If sf <> "." And sf <> ".." Then
        If (GetAttr(StartFolder & sf) And vbDirectory) <> 0 Then
                subF.Add StartFolder & sf
        End If
    End If
    sf = Dir()
Loop

For Each s In subF
    GetFiles CStr(s), Pattern, True, colFiles
Next s

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub BatchPrint()

Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

Set colFiles = New Collection

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row

With Sheet1

For CustRow = 3 To LastRow

GetFiles "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\", Sheet1.Range("B" & CustRow) & ".pdf", True, colFiles

Next CustRow

End With

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
FollowHyperlink colFiles(i)

Next i

Set colFiles = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added some lines to the code. in the variable countFiles the number of the found files are stored before getting the next one. If it was not found the number of found files remains. In this case the cell will be colored.

```
Sub BatchPrint()

Dim colFiles As New Collection
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

Set colFiles = New Collection

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row
Dim countFiles As Integer 'Storing the number of files found
With Sheet1

For CustRow = 3 To LastRow
countFiles = colFiles.Count
GetFiles "C:\Users\Desktop\Test\", Sheet1.Range("B" & CustRow) & ".pdf", True, colFiles
If countFiles = colFiles.Count Then
'No new files, shall change the color of the cell
Sheet1.Range("B" & CustRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next CustRow

End With

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
FollowHyperlink colFiles(i)

Next i

Set colFiles = Nothing

End Sub
```