# Opening/Retrieving File Via Name in VBA With Variable Folder Names

Tags: excel, vba

I am a semi-green build and deploy specialist, in which I am responsible for deploying various different code bases to different applications across a variety of environments on a regular basis. I am trying to improve my work flow by creating a VBA script that grabs the current Build/Version Number of an application.

As code is deployed to a specific server/environment, there is a .txt file that contains something along the lines of:

```
<Version Number>V5.65.3</Version Number>
```

I am trying to build a script that accesses this file and grabs the version number and inputs it into the desired cell.

My problem is that the file path contains folder names that are variable.. These are folders in a temp directory that will change each time a new version is deployed to the application. See an example file path below:

```
\\servername\constantFolder\applicationName\temp\constantFolder\temp\**RANDOMSTRING**\**RANDOMSTRING2**\constantFolder\constantFolder\FileIWant.txt
```

The issue in essence is that each time a new build is deployed, the two "RandomString" folders are created with names that are not consistent. The rest of the file path is consistent, so how can I retrieve the "FileIWant.txt" with  the two folders that may not have a consistent name?

I tried using DIR() function in the following way, but I don't believe that what I am trying to do can be accomplished with DIR() unless I am misunderstanding.

```
Dir("\\server\constantFolder\applicationName\temp\*\constantFolder\constantFolder\FileIWant.txt")
```

I have also tried to concatenate within the DIR function, but I receive a Run-Time Error "52": Bad File Name or Number.

Is there a way to retrieve a file in VBA that contains variable folder names? I have searched other questions but found that they are trying to retrieve a file with a wildcard on the file name. Here, I know the file name but will not always know the name of two intermediary folders.

Comment: You could search for all _FileIWant.txt_ in the temp folder (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688126/17172829) , and then get the newest of these files.

Comment: Possible the "easiest" method assuming know C# and COM interlop create a type library for the required function.  Eg [DirectoryGetFilesExample.bas](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-DotNetLib/blob/main/VBA/Examples/System/IO/Directory/Methods/DirectoryGetFilesExample.bas) might be a relevant VBA example and add the optional parameter SearchOption_AllDirectories.  i.e. Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, searchOption) .  Could utilize the type library developed thou WARNING it's work in progress. Or could utilize what required to create a custom type library.

Comment: Thank you both, I actually found another solution that resolves my issue and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to complete what I wanted by using DIR() directly to find the name of the variable folders' names. Both folder names contained a word (temp & content) prior to the random string of characters which allowed me to concatenate the entire path together.

See below:

```
sub get_version() 

Dim tempFolder As String
Dim ContentFolder As String
Dim FullPath As String

tempFolder = Dir("\\servername\staticFolder1\staticFolder2\applicationFolder\staticFolder3\temp*", vbDirectory)

tempContentFolder = Dir("\servername\staticFolder1\staticFolder2\applicationFolder\staticFolder3\" & tempFolder & "\content*", vbDirectory)

FullPath = "\\servername\staticFolder1\staticFolder2\applicationFolder\staticFolder3\" & tempFolder & "\" & tempContentFolder & "\staticFolder4\staticFolder5\FileIWant.txt"

End Sub
```

Since there is never another folder in that exact directory with the same starting string, it works for my solution. Thank you all for who answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found an easy solution.
If you ever have to select between multiple folders in the future you could utilize something like this:

```
Sub ListFolders()
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim f As Object, fs As Object, path As String
    
    path = "C:\"

    Set fs = fso.GetFolder(path).SubFolders
    For Each f In fs
        Debug.Print f.Name 'or if you prefer Debug.Print f.path
    Next
End Sub
```

This will print the names of all the subfolders in say drive C, and you could then add criteria to pick just one.

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you! This also seems like a viable solution, thank you! I will keep this in mind for the future.